# Google Chrome Extension save data localy

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm developing Chrome Extension that runs on my_webpage.com and request user to log in to see the web page. So I need to store password somewhere locally, first I used local storage but the problem is that it won't load data on my_webpage.com when data is saved localy in settings. Is there any other option to read/write data locay with Chrome Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`chrome.storage` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) was created specifically for that purpose.

It's available both to extension scripts (e.g. background) and content scripts.

Note though that this storage is not considered secure (not that there are alternatives that are secure, besides using `chrome.identity` to store OAuth tokens)

Comment: Can I get data from chrome.storage (that was saved in setting page) in content script?

Comment: I think that's covered in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

for saving the username or password two things can help u

- create database and save values in tables.
- write data to file in json format and read from file to load data

Comment: I can't create database locally with chrome extension